# Can't update packages on Kali Linux after modifying sources.list

Tags: kali-linux

After modifying the *sources.list* then also getting problem in installing any software.

```
root@afaque:~/Desktop# apt-get update
Err:1 http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]
E: The repository 'http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What does your sources list say and in what way did you modify it?

Answer (score 4):

The correct `sources.list` to use with Kali Linux is shown in the [Kali sources.list Repositories documentation](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories).

According to that documentation, the contents of `sources.list` should be (for the current release of Kali Linux, since the release of Kali 2016.1)

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

The documentation also says

> Any additional repositories added to the Kali `sources.list` file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.

Related: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)